# Is skin effect applicable to pulsed DC systems?

Tags: skin-effect

Unlike AC, the direction of DC never changes. If the current varies with time, should there be enough variation in the magnetic field to cause redistribution of the current?

Answer (score 4):

You really pretty much answered your own question — it's the relative change (over time) in the current (*dI/dt*) and the magnetic field (*dH/dt*) that gives rise to the skin effect. The actual sign of either value doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

> Unlike AC, the direction of DC never changes.

That right there is a misnomer.  What is the "direction" of AC, or DC?  You have to remember that everything is relative, just like in "real life".

Picture two people on a space ship throwing a ball to each other.  That ball is the AC signal.

If the ship is in orbit around earth, then from our point of view the ball is moving backwards and forwards.  If the ship is flying away from earth, then from our point of view only the speed of the ball changes, but it is always moving in the same direction.

The same can be said for electricity.  If we are at the same potential as the "average" potential of the waveform (what you would call ground in an AC waveform) then we see the waveform going both + and -.  If, however, we are at a different potential, then we only see the waveform moving around in the + region.  It is still the same waveform, but viewed from a different place.

So a "pulsed" DC waveform is just a pulsed AC waveform seen from a different reference point.

In a wire there is no reference point to compare things to, so there is no difference between the two.  They both have an "average" point which could be considered a kind of virtual reference point.  Both go + and - compared to that reference point.  The only difference between a pure sine AC waveform and a pulsed DC waveform is the frequency components.